# Use of success / jsonpCallback with ajax request

Tags: ajax, callback, jsonp, odata

I'm developing an application for Netflix using their OData API. I've followed [Stephen Walther's blog entry](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/04/01/netflix-jquery-jsonp-and-odata.aspx) on how to query the OData API. In it, he uses the following code:

```
$.ajax({
   dataType: "jsonp",
   url: query,
   jsonpCallback: "callback",
   success: callback
});
```

In my application, I need to use the OData's paging links, to retrieve the full listings. My code is as follows:

```
// create url and handle ajax call to Netflix
  function getTitles() {
    query = "http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog" // netflix odata base url
    + "/Genres('Television')" // select Genre
    + "/Titles" // top-level resource
    + "?$select=NetflixApiId,Name,BoxArt,Synopsis,ReleaseYear,AverageRating,Series" // choose fields 
    + "&$orderby=Name" // Sort results by name
    + "&$filter=Instant/Available eq true"  // filter by instant view
    + " and Type eq 'Season'" // select only seasons
    + "&$expand=Series" // include series data
    + "&$callback=callback" // specify name of callback function
    + "&$format=json"; // json request
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: query,
      jsonpCallback: "callback",
      success: callback,
      error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(textStatus + ":" + errorThrown);
      } 
    });
  }

// create seasons array and and repeat ajax call until all results are returned 
  function callback(result) {
    seasons = seasons.concat(result["d"]["results"]);
    if (typeof result["d"]["__next"] != 'undefined') {
      var urlJSONP = result["d"]["__next"] + "&$callback=callback&$format=json";
      $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: urlJSONP,
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        success: callback,
        error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          alert(textStatus + ":" + errorThrown);
        } 
      });
    } else {
      processResults();
    }
  }
```

However, when this runs I keep getting a `parserError`. It appears that the callback function is being called twice. If I remove the `success: callback` line, the application works fine. My question is: Is there a problem with leaving the `success` line of code from the ajax call? Or why would it be necessary to include both the `jsonpCallback` and `success` lines? I'm mainly asking this out of curiosity, because the application seems to work fine without both callback lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what your code is trying to do, I'm not sure why you're specifying both `jsonpCallback` and `success` in your `$.ajax` call.  I would suggest you just specify `success` in order to process your data and handle your paging.  Let jQuery define the name of your jsonp callback.

Essentially what the jsonp callback is doing is receiving the payload from your WCF Data Service and then handing it to your success handler.  It looks like you could use `jsonpCallback` if you wanted to do some caching or some other pre-processing of the data before it gets handled by your `success` handler.  I'm not sure why you'd specify the same function as both your `jsonpCallback` and `success` handlers in this case.  (I briefly looked through Stephen's article that you linked to, and I'm not why he does this.)

Below is a sample jsonp call to a WCF Data Service that I use in demos and talks (and have been using for a little while).  I use the `JSONPSupportBehaviorAttribute` in order to enable JSONP in my WCF Data Service (not sure if that's what you're using or not).

But in my sample code, I don't specify a `jsonpCallback` name; I just specify the `jsonp` querystring parameter (has to be `$callback` instead of the default `callback`), but I let jQuery name the jsonp callback function.

My `success` handler is called once and everything works fine.  So my suggestion is to forget about `jsonpCallback`, keep your `success` handler in place, and I think things should start to work better.

I hope this helps.  Let me know if you have follow-on questions.  Good luck!

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://server:25812/Services/AgileWays.Baseball.Service.svc/Teams?$format=json&$filter=yearID eq 1882',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    jsonp: '$callback',
    error: function (x, t, r) { alert(x.response.message); },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function (i, val) {
            $("#results").append("<div>" + val.name + "</div>");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't define `callback`, because jQuery creates that function for you. Here's an example, [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e8yYB/1/):

```
function getTitles() {
    query = "http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog" // netflix odata base url
    + "/Genres('Television')" // select Genre
    + "/Titles" // top-level resource
    + "?$select=NetflixApiId,Name,BoxArt,Synopsis,ReleaseYear,AverageRating,Series" // choose fields 
    + "&$orderby=Name" // Sort results by name
    + "&$filter=Instant/Available eq true"  // filter by instant view
    + " and Type eq 'Season'" // select only seasons
    + "&$expand=Series" // include series data
    + "&$callback=?" // specify name of callback function
    + "&$format=json"; // json request
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: query,
      success: callback,
      error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(textStatus + ":" + errorThrown);
      } 
    });
  }
```

`callback=?` basically asks jQuery to handle all the JSONP returns.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still throws the error "parsererror: DoesntExist was not called". I'll continue researching the subject, but as far as I can see there really isn't a benefit to having both success and jsonpCallback calling the callback function. I suppose I could modify the error handling to ignore "DoesntExist was not called", but that still leaves me with my original question of why have both.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't very clear. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/e8yYB/1/ There are no errors and no callbacks defined other than success.

Comment: Ok, this works fine for the first ajax call. As did the original code.. for a single ajax call. The errors occur when subsequent ajax calls are made to retreive the rest of the results. I don't know if the errors are thrown because the requests are occuring so rapidly and the ajax call is still waiting for a response from the server from a previous request. But the errors aren't really the problem, I was just curious as to the reasoning for using both success and jsonpCallback for the callback function.