# How to get synchronous result for jsonpCallback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, jsonp

I want to call jsonpcallback function in while or for loop. But I am getting asynchronous results. How to achieve that in jsonpcallback. Kindly anyone help me out to fix this or provide any other solution.

```
window.onPublitoryOebPart = function(json) {
    window.publitoryOebPartJson = json;
    content = patchEditedContent(json);
    saveOebPartToc(content);
}
i = 0;
while(i < $("#oeb_parts_count").val()) {
    return unless $("#oeb-part-file-url-"+i).length > 0
    fileUrl = $("#oeb-part-file-url-"+i).html();
    $.ajax({
        url: fileUrl,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "script",
        jsonpCallback: "onPublitoryOebPart"
    })
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript *can't* get a "synchronous" [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) result. This is because JSONP involves creating a new script element; such a dynamically created script element can only load the resource asynchronously.

Just [use the `success` callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7212065/2864740) for the JSONP request and handle the response *asynchronously*. Manually specifying the `jsonpCallback` is only required/useful if the service doesn't allow a dynamic function to be specified.

If using `success` callback in a loop, it's also important to [read up on closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) (and then [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572480/please-explain-the-use-of-javascript-closures-in-loops?lq=1)).

For instance:

```
var i = 0; // Don't forget the "var"
while(i < $("#oeb_parts_count").val()) {
    var elm = $("#oeb-part-file-url-"+i);
    if (!elm.length) { return; } // Make sure to use valid syntax
    var fileUrl = elm.html();
    $.ajax({
        url: fileUrl,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "script",
        success: function (i, fileUrl) {
            // Return a closure, the i and fileUrl parameters above
            // are different variables than the i in the loop outside.
            return function (data) {
                // Do callback stuff in here, you can use i, fileUrl, and data
                // (See the links for why this works)
                alert("i: " + i + " data: " + data);
            };
        })(i, fileUrl) // invocation "binds" the closure
    });
    i++;
}
```

It may be cleaner simply to create a closure via a named function, but it's all the same concept.

---

Synchronous XHR requests are also highly discouraged; XHR is *not* JSONP, even though such requests are also created with the `jQuery.ajax` function.

Comment: Then How to achieve this? Is that possible to pass i value in jsonpcallback function?

Comment: @user2138489 Simply use the `success` callback (jQuery will synthesize a proxy function) and handle the result *asynchronously*. You may also need to read up on closures, but the end result is the same - JSONP *must* be used asynchronously.

Comment: Yes I tried with success, but it didnt workout. But am not sure whether my try was correct. I just give alert json in success function but got undefined

Comment: @user2138489 Start with using `success` - then fix it and/or find out why it "doesn't work". See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7212065/2864740

Comment: I removed jsonpcallback and calling a function from success is working. But how to pass extra params to a function? because "json" variable is a default param for that function which I not pass anything while calling it. Now I want to pass i variable to that function.

Comment: @user2138489 I've updated with a trivial example of a closure; see the links for more informaiton.

Comment: Its a coffee script. I am converting it into JavaScript here. No need of defining variable in coffeescript

Comment: @user2138489 Then that is the most non-CoffeeScript "CoffeeScript" I have ever seen. Unless you're going to learn about and *use* CoffeeScript (which is fine), just use JavaScript - this poor hybrid has so much unlove. At the very least, *appropriately tag* questions.